# Color map in boost graph breadth_first_visit

Tags: c++, boost, properties, graph

I want to use boosts `breadth_first_visit` method and i'd like to provide it with my own "external" color map.
I defined the graph as follows

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, 
  boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, 
  boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type, 
  Node_t>>>  GraphType;
```

where `Node_t` is a struct, defining the properties for the vertices. However, i can't find out how i can provide the BFS with my own color map. I'd like to store the vertex colors in a vector, so my definition looks like

```
std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors;
```

but i can't figure it out, how to use this for the bfs.

Neither

```
boost::breadth_first_search(g, *boost::vertices(g).first, 
  boost::color_map(colors));
```

nor

```
boost::breadth_first_search(g, *boost::vertices(g).first, 
  boost::color_map(&colors[0]));
```

is working. While the first gives me a bunch of different compiler errors (e.g. default-int is not supported, "boost::color_traits" use of class type requires type argument list) the second compile aborts with only C2664 : 'boost::put' cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void*' to 'ptrdiff_t'.

So the question is: How can i use my own color-mapping-structure. An additional question would be: How can i get the color-value for a specific vertex_descriptor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, i used another approach but solved my problem. For those who are as confused as i was about color maps in boost or those who are interested:

The Type of the color map, as bfs uses it is:

```
typedef boost::property_map<GraphType, boost::vertex_color_t>::type color_map_t;
color_map_t colorMap; //Create a color map
```

This maps `vertex_descriptor` to (in my case) `default_color_type`. The appropriate call to boost's bfs would be

```
boost::breadth_first_visit(g, *boost::vertices(g).first, boost::color_map(colorMap));
```

Given a color_names structure that maps the color number like

```
const char* color_names[] = {"white", "gray", "green", "red", "black"};
```

one could iterate through the colors by iterating over all vertices in the graph and using the vertex_descriptor of the current vertex as an argument for the []-operator in the color map:

```
GraphType::vertex_iterator it, itEnd;
for (boost::tie(it, itEnd) = boost::vertices(g); it != itEnd; it++)
{
  std::cout << "Color of node " << *it << " is " << color_names[colorMap[*it]] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In `boost::breadth_first_visit(g, *boost::vertices(g).first, boost::color_map(colorMap));` you're not passing a visitor - what is the signature to pass a visitor and a color map?

Comment: phew, thats quite a long time ago ;) i did not try this out, but [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_visit.html) you find the second signature with an `BFSVisitor`-class as argument.

Comment: I think I figured it out actually - it is using the "named argument" signature. I don't know how you are supposed to know which names are valid arguments, but for `breadth_first_search` it seems that `visitor` is one and `color_map` is another.

Comment: @DavidDoria Documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_visit.html

Answer (score 0):

I find this [doc](https://dgtal.org/doc/stable/moduleBoostGraphWrapping.html) very helpful in understanding BGL colormap and its usage in BFS algorithms.

Here is a modern C++ solution with an external colormap.

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9b4fed37a497d1c)

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/pending/queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using MyGraph =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
using MyVertex = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;
using MyColorMap = std::map<MyVertex, boost::default_color_type>;

// https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/boost/graph/properties.hpp
// enum default_color_type { white_color, gray_color, green_color, red_color,
// black_color };
const std::unordered_map<int, std::string> int_to_color_str{
    {0, "White"}, {1, "Gray"}, {2, "Green"}, {3, "Red"}, {4, "Black"}};

int main() {
  MyGraph g{};
  boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
  boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
  boost::add_edge(1, 3, g);

  auto root = boost::vertex(0, g);
  boost::queue<MyVertex> q;
  boost::default_bfs_visitor vis;
  MyColorMap color_map;

  auto print_colors = [&]() {
    for (auto [it, it_end] = boost::vertices(g); it != it_end; it++) {
      std::cout << "Color of node " << *it << " is "
                << int_to_color_str.at(color_map[*it]) << std::endl;
    }
  };

  std::cout << "Before traversal\n";
  print_colors();

  boost::breadth_first_search(
      g, root, q, vis, boost::associative_property_map<MyColorMap>(color_map));

  std::cout << "After traversal\n";
  print_colors();
}
```